# How to suppress output in R?

Tags: r

I need to supress output in **R language** - same as in Matlab with semicolon.

I found `invisible()` and `sink()`, but nothing works for me same way. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Maybe `?capture.output`.

Comment: `capture.output(cars, file = "/dev/null")` works, but I guess only on unix - any better and more universal solution?

Comment: Assign the return the value to a vector to be removed immediately after: `s <- capture.output(print(1:1000)); rm(s)`.

Comment: Well, that works (but felling hacky). Thanks for working solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested from Rui, can return output to a vector and remove that vector immediately: `s <- capture.output(print(1:1000)); rm(s)`